# How to fix cloud rising?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I have a cloud image which is supposed to rise while user scrolling down but it's being clipped at the bottom and, therefore, looks ugly. The image itself is good. It seems to me that I have to change CSS in some way. How can I fix that?

Here's [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/NGmqzb) sandbox.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="front" id="front">
  <div class="cloud">
    <div class="scroll-arrows">
      SCROLL TO MOVE THE CLOUD
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 1000vh;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.front {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/v1448008261/cloud.png") no-repeat 50% 50%/cover;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 100vh;
}

.front .cloud {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**JS**

```
front = document.getElementById('front');

var timeOut;
window.onresize = function() {
  if(timeOut)
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
  timeOut = setTimeout(draw, 10);
}

window.onload = draw;
window.onscroll = navigate;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

forest = new Image;
forest.src = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/33/1561150.jpg';

function navigate() { draw() }

function draw(scroll) {
  scroll = (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / (document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight) * 3000;
  canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);


drawImageProp(ctx, forest, 0, (-scroll*3.9)/4, canvas.width, canvas.height + (scroll*3.9)/2);

}

function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        x = y = 0;
        w = ctx.canvas.width;
        h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    // default offset is center
    offsetX = typeof offsetX === "number" ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = typeof offsetY === "number" ? offsetY : 0.5;

    // keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;


    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        nw = iw * r,   // new prop. width
        nh = ih * r,   // new prop. height
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    // decide which gap to fill
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
    if (nh < h) ar = h / nh;
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    // calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    // make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    // fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch, x, y, w, h);

}
```

Comment: Image is not loading in codepen

Comment: @r2_d2 it's loaded, just wait a sec.

Comment: Simply removing `absolute` positioning front `.front` and giving it a fixed height makes it not clip [example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/jbRbZp) is this what you're after or is there some reason you need it to be positioned absolute.

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan It fixed the issue. Create an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the `.front` div a set height fixes the problem insted of it being `position:absolute`

Code

```
.front {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/active-bridge/image/upload/v1448008261/cloud.png") no-repeat 50% 50%/cover;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 850px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 100vh;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/jbRbZp)